# curl equivalent post request in python 3

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests

I have to write following curl script in python 3

```
curl -X POST\
-u '$client_id:$client_secret'\
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&access_lifetime=7200'
 https://www.example.com/oauth/token
```

I tried doing this

```
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'access_lifetime': '7200'}
response_result = requests.post(
    'https://www.example.com/oauth/token',
    data=json.dumps(data),
    auth=('client_id', 'client_secret)
)
```

But on `print(response_result.text)` it gives error as `The grant type was not specified in the request`

I think the `data` is not passing or I'm using wrong way to pass `data`.

**How to pass data in the `requests`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a dictionary to the `data` keyword argument, not a JSON string:

```
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'access_lifetime': '7200'}
response_result = requests.post(
    'https://www.example.com/oauth/token',
    data=data,
    auth=('client_id', 'client_secret)
)
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for details.

Answer (score -1):

data=data

Instead of

data=json.dumps(data)